# How to change MDCTextField placeholder text color?

Tags: ios, material-components, material-components-ios

I'm currently using it with `MDCTextInputControllerOutlined`.
I already tried

```
self.emailTextField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Email", attributes: [.font: UIFont.ralewayFont(ofSize: 18.0, weight: .semibold), .foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
```

but not working

Comment: Try to set Tint color to your emailTextField

Comment: not working also @manishsharma93

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it!
set UIColor to `inlinePlaceholderColor` for `MDCTextInputControllerOutlined`

```
let emailTextField = MDCTextField()

let emailTextFieldController = MDCTextInputControllerOutlined(textInput: emailTextField)
emailTextFieldController.inlinePlaceholderColor = .white
```

Comment: Add full line of code and accept the answer so that it will help others in future.